# Installed Windows Azure 2.3 for Visual Studio 2012. Not able to load project type .ccproj

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, azure

I have migrated azure from Versoin 1.7 to 2.3.
Now i am getting error while loading project

```
 Unsupported
This version of Visual Studio does not have the following project types installed or does not support them. You can still open these projects in the version of Visual Studio in which they were originally created.
     - ICERTIS.TMS, "D:\TMS\Source\IPM\Dev\Source\ICERTIS.TMS\ICERTIS.TMS.ccproj"


Non-functional changes required
Visual Studio will automatically make non-functional changes to the following projects in order to enable them to open in this version and Visual Studio 2010 SP1. Project behavior will not be impacted.
     - ICERTIS.TMS, "D:\TMS\Source\IPM\Dev\Source\ICERTIS.TMS.sln"
```

I am using professional version of Visual studio 2012 but this must not be the concerned.
Also in activity.xml file under path showing following error:

```
 C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0
Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Windows Azure Tools\v2.1\Microsoft.VisualStudio.WindowsAzure.2.1.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

what???